# Apply delta_E_CMC between to groups of pixels efficiently

Tags: python

I want to apply: [delta_E_CMC](https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/develop/generated/colour.difference.delta_E_CMC.html) between 2 groups of LAB pixels. One group is the image itself. Another group is a subset of pixels from other image.

I'm using Python and my main issue here is performance, thus I'm looking for **efficient** ways to calculate delta_E_CMC between all the pixels in image A to a group B, subset of pixels from different image.

Comment: why the opencv tag? you're using the "colour" module, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you've linked performs the calculation using pretty efficient vectorized operations on numpy arrays already.

The following implementation should be pretty fast, but could get memory-hungry if you're working with very large images.

```
import numpy as np
from colour.difference import delta_E_CMC

img_colors = np.random.random((21, 3)) # An array of colors from your first image
palette = np.random.random((5,3)) # A subset of pixels

 # We need to repeat so there are img_colors.shape[0] * palette.shape[0] elements in each array
color_dist = delta_E_CMC(
    np.repeat(img_colors, palette.shape[0], axis=0),     
    np.repeat(palette, img_colors.shape[0], axis=1).reshape(img_colors.shape[0]*palette.shape[0],3, order='F') 
).reshape(img_colors.shape[0], palette.shape[0])

# color_dist[i,j] is the distance between img_colors[i] and palette[j]
```

If you're running into memory issues, you can probably get away with applying the code above in a for loop, using a subset of `img_colors` every time.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy's array operations to compute delta_E_CMC on numerous pixels at once, as opposed to Python loops, is known as vectorizing calculations. Since numpy's array operations are done in C and can be several orders of magnitude quicker than identical Python code, this is frequently the single most important optimization you can make.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm away of this, could you provide an example that uses delta_E_CMC, an image and a group of pixels to show how it can be done.